# How to fix python `dlib` error: "symbol not found in flat namespace '_png_do_expand_palette_rgb8_neon'"?

Tags: python, dlib

I am getting the error: `symbol not found in flat namespace '_png_do_expand_palette_rgb8_neon'`
The error occurs in spite of the `dlib` package being installed for the relevant Python version.

I am using VSCode, in case that is relevant.

Can anyone please help me to fix this bug?
[image]

Answer (score 6):

For me, this is a mac M1 specific issue, solved by linking libpng:

```
brew install libpng
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpng/1.6.37/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpng/1.6.37/lib
pip3 install dlib --force-reinstall
```

(replace 1.6.37 by your installed version of libpng)

Answer (score 4):

Should work if you force a reinstall using:

pip3 install dlib --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir --global-option=build_ext

That fixed it for me.

Comment: Well, it doesn't.

Comment: worked for me but I had to run `pip3 install cmake`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to install dlib from source:

```
git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git
cd dlib
python setup.py install --set DLIB_PNG_SUPPORT=1 --compiler-flags "-I/usr/local/include -L/opt/homebrew/lib -lpng"
```

This was based on [this issue on dlib](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/2524) which recommends installing libpng and [this issue on homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/2625) which recommends adding the `--compiler-flags`.

Installing libpng and setting the compiler flags didn't make the error go away, and in desperation I went into `dlib/image_save/save_png.h` to comment out the assert. However, there was a helpful commend in the code:

```
#ifndef DLIB_PNG_SUPPORT
            /* !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                You are getting this error because you are trying to use save_png()
                but you haven't defined DLIB_PNG_SUPPORT.  You must do so to use
                this function.   You must also make sure you set your build environment
                to link against the libpng library.
            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*/
            COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(sizeof(image_type) == 0);
#else
...
```

Given that I have libpng, I set DLIB_PNG_SUPPORT and building succeeded.

Then ensure your virtual environment is active (if applicable) and install it:

```
python -m pip install .
```