# How to fix error: "symbol not found in flat namespace (_png_do_expand_palette_rgb8_neon)" when trying to import dlib?

Tags: python, macos, dlib

I am getting error: "symbol not found in flat namespace (_png_do_expand_palette_rgb8_neon)" when trying to import dlib into Python using VSCode.

I am using a M1 MacBook Pro and I am aware that other people have ran into this problem before but no suggested solution I have tried has worked for me.

Would anyone please be able to help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to this [issue on github](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/2524#issuecomment-1050495674).

This is caused by the **libpng** on your system, use the following command may solve it:

```
python3 setup.py install --no DLIB_PNG_SUPPORT
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but when I enter this into the terminal I am given this error `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/andrewwaddell/setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Can this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73603872/18359438) solve your issue?

Comment: I have also tried every answer to the question you suggested but am still given the same errors

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling dlib then installing it again at version 19.20.0 fixed it for me.

```
pip install dlib==19.20.0
```